# How to use i18n with material design's md-floating-label?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need to make the label inside md-floating-label editable, so that for different locales we can have different texts. But i am not able to figure out how as i am quite new to Material-Design.

I am using md-floating-label attribute with `<md-autocomplete>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use angular translate : https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate it's easy, ou will just have  to replace it by a key.

```
md-floating-label="{'label' | translate}}"
```